# passing parameter to view in IOS after a button is pressed

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to IOS programming. So far I have been programming in android. So in android when pressing a button code for passing an argument would be like that:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainScreen.this,OtherScreen.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("data_1",data);
i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(i);
```

and on the activity that opens, i would write something like this:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
ski_center=b.getString("data_1");
```

what methods should I need to change in MainScreen and in OtherScreen in IOS to achieve the above.

Basically I will have 3 buttons lets say in my MainScreen and each of it will open the Otherview but each time a different parameter will be passed.

Foe example for each button i have code like these in MainScreen.m

```
@synthesize fl;
-(IBAction) ifl:(id) sender {
}
```

So I need your help in where to place the "missing" code, too.

Comment: there are no intents. you would be calling the otherview's constructors directly.

Comment: @govi: In the most (common) cases you do not create the view directly. You create controller hierarchies. I think ghostrider's question went more into a basics direction of the concepts of iOS resp. Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare an iVar for your UIViewController ( Android's Activity) like a property in Java.

In MainViewController.m

```
OtherUIViewController * contr = [[OtherUIViewController alloc] initWithNibname...];
contr.data = yourData;
```

Edited: added full code...

Intent i = new Intent(MainScreen.this,OtherScreen.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("data_1",data);

here the MainScreen is the calling code, now in iOS it will be the MainUIViewcontroller

- create a OtherUIViewController like this:

OtherUIViewController.h

```
@interface OtherUIViewController : UIViewController
{
       NSData* data;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSData* data;
```

in the OtherUIViewController.m

```
@implementation OtherUIViewController.m
@synthetize data;

// override
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// do something with data here
}
```

to have the 3 different behaviors, the data can be an int, or an NSString. 
And in the  `- (void)viewDidLoad` you will check the `data` value and do 3 diff things.

I hope it helps

Comment: so to make it clear, I am declaring an ivar in my OtherView.h
and in myScreen.m I am adding the following code in my IBaction?
(where IBaction is the function that triggers the change of the view).
Right?

Comment: In .h declare ivar and @property too, in .m declare the @ synthesize for property. Than use the code above given, than you will push to a wievcontroller this controller, which will trigger a lot of functions in UIViewcontroler lifecycle, and from one of than you will use the given param, like in:  viewDidload

Comment: Ok I got it. So my final question is where to place the given code? In the MainScreen.m or in OtherView.m? I guess in MainScreen. And if yes in which of its methods?

Comment: as I can see, I  need to edit my answer and write the code each step :( It will be hard for you to complete your project, but I came from Android me too. Editing answer to have detailed.

Comment: its ok more or less I have figured it out. The only thing I dont know is where to place that code. In my edited answer is one IBAction I do have. is that the place whee I should place that code or elsewhere?